# Re Ask for remaining permissions on authenticate Facebook user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I integrate Facebook app on android and request for Login with "public_profile,email,user_friends,user_photos" permissions first time.
When login I restrict email permission. Now when I'm going to authenticate second  time it saying "You have already authorized App". Whereas it should ask for remaining permissions again.
If in future I need email permission then how can I permit it.Is there any way for it.

here is screen

[image: edit permission screen]

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the user has declined a permission, your app can not simply ask for it again the same way – you need to explicitly re-ask for it, by passing the parameter `auth_type=rerequest` in the login dialog call.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#handling

Comment: Thaks @CBroe, this one is also useful for us. but Is there any to prevent user  to proceed further if he unchecked any permission that we required and show an alert for it ?

Comment: Not directly on the login dialog, no. You have to check what permissions your app got granted afterwards.